# Do i need to install the packages again on ec2 micro if stopped

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 micro instance(ubuntu) running with tomcat and apache installed . 
I am confused what happens if the system crashes , or shuts down. or If i stop it.

1. Will i have to install and configure all the packages(tomcat,apache) again on the instance , or will the instance on restart or reboot will have all these packages in the pre-stop state?
2. I know micro instance uses EBS for storage. And I assume on stop it maintains the state (i.e. it is not deleted). is it?
3. So on restart only the IP address changes right?
4. Or do i need to configure the instance again.

Comment: It would totally depend on is you made any configuration changes that took place outside the EBS volume.

Comment: You should not have to reconfigure anything on your instance once it's been set up.

Comment: @MikeBrant Since micro doesnt have a local instance storage, everything is stored in EBS volume (My assumption),so all the configuration changes for tomcat or apache would be stored in EBS.. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @MichaelJCox So apart from the IP address change(since i dont have elastic ip address), there is nothing that I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much spot on with all your assumptions:

All EBS backed instances retain their installation state and configuration, which under normal circumstances shouldn't ever have any parts located on the (often called *ephemeral*) instance store volume(s), if any (see [Root Device Storage Concepts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#RootDeviceStorageConcepts) for a detailed explanation of the differences between EBS and instance store backed AMIs).

Given the [Amazon EC2 Instance Type](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) `t1.micro` is *EBS storage only* indeed, this is guaranteed in your case.

- Interestingly *EBS storage only* also applies to the newest regular instance types m3.xlarge and m3.2xlarge btw., so AWS might be slowly moving away from instance storage eventually.

Likewise, *on restart only the IP address changes*, be it a default public one or an Elastic IP address, see e.g. the FAQ [Do I need one Elastic IP address for every instance that I have running?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Do_I_need_one_Elastic_IP_address_for_every_instance_that_I_have_running):

> No. You do not need an Elastic IP address for all your instances. By
>   default, every instance comes with a private IP address and an
>   internet routable public IP address. The private address is associated
>   exclusively with the instance and is only returned to Amazon EC2 when
>   the instance is stopped or terminated. **The public address is
>   associated exclusively with the instance until it is stopped,
>   terminated or replaced with an Elastic IP address**. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

- Please note that EC2 instances started within an [Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) slightly differ here, insofar they don't have get a default public IP address and do retain an Elastic IP address (if any) throughout a stop/start cycle.